# Avoid duplicate values when grouping a table by itself

Tags: sql-server

Table : employee

```
empid depti salary hired_date
1   1   4000    2012-01-01
2   1   3000    2015-11-01
3   1   3000    2015-01-11
4   2   4000    2015-11-01
5   1   3000    2014-11-01
6   2   5000    2015-01-01
```

Query:

```
select emp1.empid, emp1.salary as higher, emp2.empid, emp2.salary as lower_sal
from employee as emp1, employee as emp2
where emp1.salary >= 4000 and emp2.salary < 4000 
group by emp1.empid, emp2.empid, emp1.salary, emp2.salary
```

Above Queries Result:

```
empid higher empid lower_sal
1   4000    2   3000
1   4000    3   3000
1   4000    5   3000
4   4000    2   3000
4   4000    3   3000
4   4000    5   3000
6   5000    2   3000
6   5000    3   3000
6   5000    5   3000
```

Expected Result:

```
empid higher empid lower_sal
1   4000    2   3000
4   4000    3   3000
6   5000    5   3000
```

what's needed to be included in the query to get this output and avoid the duplicate values.

Comment: I can't work out what you're trying to do, or why you would expect that result. It looks like you're just trying to display a single result set in a 2 column layout?

Comment: More specifically, why is id 1 related to id 2, but not id 3 & 5. Likewise why is id 4 related to id 3 but not id 2 & 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following query

```
select i1.empid,i1.higher,i2.empid,i2.lower_sal from (
select emp1.empid, emp1.salary as higher,rank() over(order by empid) rnk
from employee as emp1
where emp1.salary >= 4000 )i1 join(
select emp2.empid, emp2.salary as lower_sal,rank() over(order by empid) rnk
from  employee as emp2
where emp2.salary < 4000 )i2 on i1.rnk=i2.rnk
```

the result is as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using distinct yet? This is a clause you can add to indicate that you do not want duplicate values. Add it after the 'Select'.

```
select distinct emp1.empid, emp1.salary as higher, emp2.empid, emp2.salary as lower_sal
from employee as emp1, employee as emp2
where emp1.salary >= 4000 and emp2.salary < 4000 
group by emp1.empid, emp2.empid, emp1.salary, emp2.salary
```

Comment: yes tried with the distinct, but returns same duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can use cross apply,

```
SELECT      *
FROM        Employee A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Min(B.Salary) AS Min_Salary
             FROM   Employee B
             WHERE B.salary < 4000)B 
WHERE  A.Salary >= 4000
```

Comment: the basic requirement is to display the employee having salary >= 4000 as higher and salary < 4000 as lower with the empid respectively. the CROSS APPLY returns the empid of Higher, but I also i need the empid of lower.